# Problems upgrading Git with Homebrew

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion, homebrew

I'm very close here, I think I just need to create a symbolic link, but I'm not sure how (and why this is need).

I downloaded and installed git using this command:

```
brew install git
```

The response is:

```
git-1.7.12 already installed, it's just not linked
```

How do I do this?

When I run:

```
which git
>/usr/bin/git
```

When I run:

```
git --version
>git version 1.7.4.4
```

My paths are fine:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Again, all I really need to know is how to set up the symlink.

Comment: Why are you asking the [exact same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362027/problems-installing-git-with-homebrew)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By using the `link` subcommand:

```
brew link git
```