# Problems installing Git with Homebrew

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion, homebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems Upgrading Git with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362021/problems-upgrading-git-with-homebrew)

I'm very close here -- I think I  just need to create a symbolic link, but I'm not sure how (and why this is need). I'm on OSX Lion btw.

I've downloaded and installed git using this command.

```
brew install git
```

the response is

```
git-1.7.12 already installed, it's just not linked
```

How do I do this?

when I run

```
which git
>/usr/bin/git
```

when I run

```
git --version
>git version 1.7.4.4
```

My paths are fine

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Again -- all I really need to know is how to set up the sym link. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running `brew doctor`? What is the output?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/12362021/1451820

Answer (score 73, accepted):

All you should need to do is:

```
brew link git
```

Comment: That gives me "No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git"

Comment: Try `brew update` then `brew install git`

Comment: That helped. I still had a PATH issue to work out (moving /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin), but you led me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: After an update I actually had to `brew link --overwrite mysql`

Comment: @jamesnotjim How do you do that? I'm new to OSX and getting confused trying to fix the same path issue.

Comment: @AlexFord You launch the Terminal app. It should default to your home directory. Then you'll use a text editor to modify the .bash_profile file (note the dot at the beginning). I use nano, so the command to edit it would be `nano .bash_profile`. You'll find a line like this one:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin`

What you're seeing there is a series of paths, separated by a colon. In my case, `/usr/local/bin` came after `/usr/bin`, and that was messting things up. 

So, I modified that and then saved the changes.