# Error linking git to homebrew

Tags: git, terminal, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I'm following [Luke Jones' article on setting up a local server](http://lukejones.me/archives/set-up-a-local-server-on-osx), and I'm currently trying to set up homebrew with git on Mavericks. I already had git installed before installing homebrew. I'm having an issue that seemed similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362021/problems-upgrading-git-with-homebrew) but when I tried running `brew link git` I received the following error:

```
Error: Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.5.1/share/git-core/templates/info/exclude
Target /usr/local/share/git-core/templates/info/exclude already exists. You may need to delete it.
To force the link and overwrite all other conflicting files, do:
  brew link --overwrite formula_name

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run formula_name
```

My `/etc/paths`:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

`which git` returns `/usr/bin/git`

`which brew` returns `/usr/local/bin/brew`

Not sure what the issue is, as I'm still not great at finding my way around things like this. Anyone know next steps to take?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For others having an issue in the future:

I have git linked with homebrew now. I had the [Mac Github client](http://mac.github.com/) installed which may have been making some files unwriteable ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676241/installing-git-with-homebrew-not-working) tipped me off), so I uninstalled that with [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/), restarted my terminal, uninstalled all versions of git, ran `sudo brew prune` to clean things up, and reinstalled git through brew with `brew install git`. Then I ran `brew link git` and it worked just fine.

I'm sure someone else might have a better explanation of what happened, and some of these steps might have been overkill, but it worked for me!

Answer (score 11):

Try overriding the links as suggested in the error message:

```
 brew link --overwrite git
```

You may add `--dry-run` to check it first before doing any changes.